# Datetime - problem with hour formatting

Tags: datetime, formatting

```
    Datetime t = Datetime.now();
    System.debug(t);
    System.debug(t.format('HH hh kk KK'));
```

Result:

13:37:57:233 USER_DEBUG [16]|DEBUG|2013-05-17 **11**:37:58

13:37:57:234 USER_DEBUG [17]|DEBUG|**04 04 04 04**

H,h,k,K all returned **04**, but I'm pretty sure it should be **11** instead!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format function convert the datetime variable **to local time**.

`datetime.now()` is showing **GMT**.

> format|String|Converts the date to the local time zone and returns the
>   converted date as a formatted string using the locale of the context
>   user. If the time zone cannot be determined, GMT is used.

More details: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm